# Does changing the wavevector $k$ of an electron in a band mean the same as changing its wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

If crystal momentum is transferred by a phonon to an electron with wavenumber $k$, i.e. the electron has then the wavenumber $k^\prime$, does this also change the electrons wavelength $\lambda$?
Is the formula $\lambda=2\pi/k$ valid for this problem?

Comment: Is the question this:  Does it change the wavelength of the electron wave function?

Comment: @garyp Yes, that‘s what I mean. In case you are an expert in band theory: I also want to know, if in a band there is always an electron for every *k* in the first Brillouin zone? I mean is every possible *k* value „occuppied“ with an electron? I know that there are 2N electrons per band, where N is the number of unit cells. So in an infinite crystal, there must be infinite electrons per band, right? Thank you in advance for your help!